# Import specific rows and formulas from master sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have been looking for hours now how to solve my problem, as it follows :

I want to duplicate [this master sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwZCXxC_beJ7mWas0Wl5bUcOw7l7sm3NrO9Czk1oCs4/edit?usp=sharing) a hundred times and be able to let [the end-users](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hApKeiuG9xbL5szkS3MOIRM7vww5RrkG5gwtPpGWzio/edit?usp=sharing) fill in the green cells, without breaking the IMPORTRANGE formula (cell A3).

Also keeping  the original formulas (additions and multiplications) of the master sheet within the copied sheets would be a great plus.

I have tried multi things with QUERY formulas but I just can't sort it out.

Thanks in advance to anyone helping out !

Comment: Hi @Painta! I understood that you want to copy the master Sheet multiple times, while keeping all the formulas, and share each one with a different user. If my comprehension is correct, I could write an app that accomplishes that using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive). Please, write back confirming if this answer would work in your scenario.